# Does mouseEnabled property cause Flash player to redraw the object?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, flash-cs5

So I made few text fields on the stage and launched the movie.
It appears that when I turn on the "Show redraw regions" and try to click on the text field it shows it's redrawed.

When is set the mouseEnabled property for this text field to false and try to click on the text field it doesn't show it's being redrawed.

By redrawing they mean what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because nothing happens upon a click if you set `mouseEnabled` to false, there's no way the textfield could have changed, so it doesn't need to be redrawn. If it is enabled, a click can have any number of effects (default or added yourself) so it needs to redraw the field to be sure.

Comment: Yes... Basically everything you see in the Flash Player is one bitmap - this bitmap, when needed is not redrawn completely - that would be a waste of processing time. It is only redrawn in the regions needed. So - for instance, you have a 100x100 Flash, which has a small 10x10 square which changes colours. The redrawn part (redraw region) would of course only be the 10x10 square area, and only that one will be changed in the whole bitmap.